# Overriding High DPI Scaling from CMake

Tags: cmake, windows-10, dpi, highdpi

I am compiling and building a C++ OpenCV app on Windows 10, which shows some images. When running on a system with screen scaling, I want to disable the OS scaling and show the pixels at their original/true size.

I want to overrride the high DPI scaling behavior and set it to "Application".

I can do this fine on the `.exe` file by: Right-Click->Properties->Compatibility Tab and checking the checkbox.:

[image]

Is there a CMake command or command line tool I can use to do that as part of the CMake script so that every target I choose gets built with this setting?

Comment: I got an answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/1230356/101610), will try it as part of a _CMake_ script and write up the answer.